# Html.BeginForm is not passing data to Controller - .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.beginform

I must be making a small mistake because this setup "should" be working, but my Controller isn't even hit in Debug when submit is clicked.

**HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("sendMail", "LakerLegends", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="col-xs-9">
      Name
      <br />
      <input name="name" type="text" required />
      <br />
      Email
      <br />
      <input name="email" type="text" required />
      <br />
      Category
      <br />
      <select name="category" style="font-size: 18px; padding: 0px" required>
        <option value="0">General</option>
        <option value="1">Teams</option>
        <option value="2">Events</option>
        <option value="3">Website</option>
        <option value="4">Internal</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      Details
      <br />
      <textarea name="details" cols="25" required></textarea>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Save" class="form-group" />
      <br />
      <i>An officer will contact you within the next 24 hours.</i>
    </th>
    <th colspan="1">
      <img src="/Content/img/contactIcon.png" style="opacity:.7" />
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult sendMail(string name, string email, string category, string details)
   {
      try
      {
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
         // Some code
      }
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
```

Clicking submit just seems to reload the page.

Comment: Make sure your controller name is "LakerLegendsController", this should  work fine.

Comment: It is. So confused on why this isn't working. :/

Comment: Your code is working for me. Can you check your routing config? Are you able to navigate /LakerLegends/Index ?

Comment: Yup, my routes is untouched from the auto-generated code. And this type of form setup works fine all over the rest of the site.

Comment: When I hit submit it just reloads the page it seems

Comment: Then looks js validation issue. If you are using chrome, open developer tool, see the console if it has any js errors or network tab once you click Save button(whether it is posting form or not).

Comment: @UttamKC Found the problem.... Wanna know what my stupid mistake was? I was running in release mode, not debug. *facepalm*. If you wanna make a witty answer I'll accept it for you, for your time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I hope this is use for you..

You should give id for each control in html.

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" required />
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult sendMail(FormCollection loFormCollection)
{
    string name = (loFormCollection["name"] != null && loFormCollection["name"] != "") ? loFormCollection["name"] : null;
    string email = (loFormCollection["email"] != null && loFormCollection["email"] != "") ? loFormCollection["email"] : null;

    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```